# Jquery Redirect Based on URL location

Tags: javascript, regex, redirect

This is what I'm trying to solve for...

1. Only if the URL explicitly contains /foldername/index.htm && /foldername/ on mydomain.com then redirect to http://www.example.com
2. Should the URL contain **any** URL parameter /foldername/index.htm?example it should **not redirect**
3. All other URLs should not redirect

This is my javascript which is incomplete, but is ultimately what I'm trying to solve for...

```
var locaz=""+window.location;
if (locaz.indexOf("mydomain.com") >= 0) {
    var relLoc = [
        ["/foldername/index.htm"],
        ["/foldername/"]
    ];
    window.location = "http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

This is for the purpose to manage a URL that some users are hitting based on a particular way like a bookmark. Without removing the page, we want to monitor how many people are hitting the page before we take further action.

Comment: i updated the description with the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't the page always be on the same domain, also if the url contains `/foldername/pagename.htm` won't it also already include `/foldername`? So an `&&` check there would be redundant.

Try the below code.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;

if  ( (path === '/foldername' || path === '/foldername/index.html') && !window.location.search ) {
    alert('should redirect');
} else {
    alert('should not redirect');
}
```

Comment: jack, yes it would be on the same domain, also, i updated the description for the page name to be "index.htm" since the /foldername/ is folder name without index.htm therefor should someone visit just folder name or the index.htm they would be redirected.

Comment: So essentially you can get to index.html be either going to `/foldername` or `/foldername/index.html`?

Comment: yes, this is right. apparently we have links that send users directly to /foldername/ which is the same as hitting /foldername/index.htm but there's always a / after foldername which is good

Comment: `location.pathname` would not contain `?` - that is available in `location.search`.

Comment: @rodneyrehm Thanks, overlooked that when I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm getting 'should not redirect' each time i hit my 3 conditions when it should be 'should redirect'

Comment: It might not be perfect because I can't really test it. Make sure you replaced `foldername` with the real folder name. Between these three answers you should hopefully be on the right track.

Comment: you're right, i didn't have the full path in place. this works, the only caveat is it doesn't support if there is a query parameter such as ?

Comment: @Evan There's a typo in my answer: `searh` should be `search`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location;
var regexDomain = /mydomain\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*[\/\.a-z]*$/    
if(regexDomain.test(url)) { 
  window.location = "http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

Comment: This looks to solve for the parameter and the domain, but not when the URL is explicitly "/foldername/pagename.htm" or "/foldername/"

Answer (score 0):

Familiarize with the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) object. It provides `pathname`, `search` and `hostname` as attributes, sparing you the RegExp hassle (you'd most like [get wrong](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/about-uris.html#problems) anyways). You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
// no redirect if there is a query string
var redirect = !window.location.search 
  // only redirect if this is run on mydomain.com or on of its sub-domains
  && window.location.hostname.match(/(?:^|\.)mydomain\.com$/)
  // only redirect if path is /foldername/ or /foldername/index.html
  && (window.location.pathname === '/foldername/' || window.location.pathname === '/foldername/index.html');

if (redirect) {
  alert('boom');
}
```